# 2D Kernel for Gausian Process Regression

Tags: regression, covariance

I want to use Gaussion Process Regression to fit a function to data. Since I know a little about the target function, I would like to build a suitable kernel from existing kernels. The input vector consists of two parameters, so my kernel or covariance function is two-dimensional.

I combined a 2D radial basis function kernel with the same variance and lengthscale on both dimensions by adding an linear kernel.

K1 = RBF(2D) + Linear (1D)

For a small local variance I added another 1D radial basis function kernel with a greater variance and lengthscale then the already used RBF-Kernel.

My result looks like:
[Surfaceplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU35w.png)
(A survace with a valley parallel to an axes / in one dimension.)

What I'm really looking for is a kernel or covariance function, that is not parallel to an axes, but has an valey across both dimensions like: [Kernel Cookbook](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/multidimensional_kernels/1d%20Function%20in%202d.png)

Has anyone a sugestion?

(Im using Python 3.10.0 with GPy.)